# Using Spritebuilder, crashing buttons

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, crash, spritebuilder

I am a 12 year old wannabe programmer so if answering, avoid being esoteric. (Use terminology a 12 year would understand)
I am creating an app using Spritebuilder.
I have two scenes: MainScene, and LevelSelect.
That's self explanatory, but just incase: A button called Play on MainScene is used to go to LevelSelect. A button on LevelSelect, Back, is used to go back to MainScene.
Problem is, every time the back button is pressed the game crashes and leads me to the word: **SIGABRT**.

It would be useful to tell me what that means as well. (Couldn't find the definition).

Button Play: Doc root var: `_playbutton`
Selector: `play`
Target: `Document root`

Button Play: Doc root var: `_backbutton`
Selector: `back`
Target: `Document root`.

I also have two files in Xcode, both subclasses of CCNode. One called MainScene and the other LevelSelect.

### MainScene.m code

```
#import "MainScene.h"
@implementation MainScene

CCButton *_playButton;
- (void)play {
    CCScene *scene = [CCBReader loadAsScene:@"LevelSelect"];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:scene];
}
```

### LevelSelect.m code

```
#import "LevelSelect.h"
@implementation LevelSelect

CCButton *_backButton;
- (void)back {
    CCScene *backScene = [CCBReader loadAsScene:@"MainScene"];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:backScene];
}
```

I have also added one Exception Breakpoint.

Exception: `Objective C`

Break: `On Throw`

Action: `Debugger Command`

Debugger Command: `de bug`

Option: `NOt checked`

After applying the breakpoint SIGABRT stopped showing up. The app simply just crashed, and didn't lead me to wrong code.

```
0x0257029e __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0256fac3              CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0256f8db              CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x03bbe9e2              GSEventRunModal + 192
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x03bbe809 GSEventRun               + 104
    23  UIKit                               0x00d3dd3b              UIApplicationMain + 1225
    24  TrapMaster                          0x00002d5c main + 92
    25  TrapMaster                          0x00002795 start + 53
    26  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type                NSException
(lldb)
```

These are the final 23 lines of code in the debug console on Xcode.

I think it may have something to do with CCDirector, sharedDirector, and replaceScene. If the answer is obvious, I'm 12. Please don't be harsh when answering stating how easy this is. If you answered, thanks. :)

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html Then run it again, and update your post with the surrounding code where it crashes (highlight the line where it crashed) and post the last couple lines of the debug console (the text area at the bottom center of Xcode). SIGABRT is a generic error, we need more info to help you debug this issue.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I have included the debugging console and breakpoint

Comment: Are you using XCode 5.1 ?

Comment: Also please update your code with the answer from your other question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22336268/member-variable-problems .

Comment: at first, you say your buttons are '_playbutton' and '_backbutton' but in your code you named them as '_playButton' and '_backButton'. Have you tried to name them with no caps?