# Member Variable Problems

Tags: objective-c, debugging, cocos2d-iphone

I have a button in Spritebuilder. Characteristics are as follows:

Doc root var: `_playbutton` | Selector: `play`Target: | `Document root`

Code for the button in Xcode:

```
CCButton *_playButton;
- (void)play {
    CCScene *scene = [CCBReader loadAsScene:@"LevelSelect"];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:scene];
}
```

LevelSelect is a seperate scene in Spritebuilder.

This code worked until I had problems with my Back button, which inhabits scene LevelSelect. To see characteristics, see my "Using Spritebuilder, Crashing Buttons" question.

My question is, why does this code show up in my debugging console?

```
CCBReader: Couldn't find member variable: _playbutton
```

The answer works, kinda. But, now in LevelSelect, Xcode can't find the Back button. This is the code:

```
@implementation LevelSelect {
CCButton *_backbutton;
}
- (void)back {
    CCScene *backScene = [CCBReader loadAsScene:@"MainScene"];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:backScene];
}
```

As you can see I have incorporated the answer.  How do you fix this?

Comment: @Ben-G I have used your idea. But now this happens:

Comment: What do you mean XCode can't find the back button? Is it the same CCBReader couldn't find member variable error? Check to see that you have copied the things `_backbutton`exactly. It is case sensitive so `_backbutton` is not the same as `_backButton`. PS: keep up the coding, wish I had these tools available when I was 12

Comment: @TiborUdvari I mean that the CCBReader can't find _backbutton, which is exactly similar to _playbutton. Just imagine the CCBReader debugger code, just with _backbutton replacing _playbutton. This happens when I open the LevelSelect scene in Spritebuilder

Comment: @TiborUdvari I tried doing what you suggested, but it didn't work. Maybe it has something to do with the 'CCDirector' and 'sharedDirector'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have placed the variable it is a global variable and not a member variable.

If you want the member variable to be private place it in the `.m` file at the following position:

```
@implementation YourClassName {
    CCButton *_playButton;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Debugging CCBReader: Couldn't find member variable XXX warnings

`CCBReader: Couldn't find member variable XXX` shows up when a connection is not set up properly. Here is a step by step workflow to check to make sure that your connections are set up properly.

These happen to me all the time because it can go badly at multiple places.

For this example I will be using a `CCButton` called `_backbutton` that is an *ivar* of the `LevelSelect` scene.

### Make sure that in **SpriteBuilder**:

1. `LevelSelect` is the custom class of your `CCScene` root node
2. Your `CCButton` is marked as `Doc root var` and the correct name is marked, also it should not be a custom class if you do not want it to be
3. Do a `File->Clean Project`
4. Press the `Publish` button

### Make sure that in **XCode**

1. You have a custom class called `LevelSelect`
2. In `LevelSelect` you have an **ivar** declared
3. Do a `Product->Clean`
4. Run your project

Ivar declaration in **SpriteBuilder**

[image: Imgur]

Ivar declaration in **Xcode**

```
@implementation LevelSelect  
{
    CCButton *_backbutton; 
}
```